# How do you say 'fey' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The title says it all: How do you say 'fey' in Esperanto?
This is a common English word:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fey

but is not in Benson, Wells, Revo, Vikivortaro.
I would like ALL the meanings translated, just as if the sources cited had themselves included the term.

Comment: Can you please specify the meaning of fey that you need a translation of? It would help if you provided some context or an example sentence.

Comment: What is Fey?  A name, or a reference to the Spanish "fe"?????

Comment: A link to a dictionary isn't really sufficient; I have a dictionary as well. There are several possible meanings, as your link shows. You need to provide us with _the specific meaning that you need_ and _the context you need it in_, lest we provide you with an incorrect or inaccurate translation. The link you gave is about an adjective _fey_, whereas the current answer refers to a noun from a specific book series, which is not mentioned in the link you provide. So you can see how counterproductive this is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the wood-dwelling characters from the Tolkien books, in *La Hobito* they have been translated as *elfo*/*elfoj* by Chris Gledhill.

Answer (score 1):

In Esperanto `feo` is the gender neutral translation for *fay* (en), *fee* (nl), *Fee* (de), *фея* (bg). Taking into account that `feino` for *fairy* as in the fairy tales is a very constricted context, **feo** is okay. It is understandable that in translation of *La Hobito* they did not want to have the "fairy" association. It would be nice to see the translations in other languages.

By the way reta-vortaro.de lists `fay` the British English spelling.

---

For the referred definition, of the adjective I did *not* find anything.
One should probably look at other languages first.

The following are not apt:

- alimonda
- sovaĝa
- aluda

Comment: If there were an entry in Benson, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Since this word does not have a single equivalent in Esperanto, there is not one single translation for this word.  Please see the examples below.

If you use the sense of [condemned](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=eo&text=doomed), you would use

> kondamnita

If you use the sense of [visionary](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=eo&text=visionary), you would use

> viziulo

Since this word has a wide variety of meanings the best approach would be to take each sense of the word and translate it by itself.